# Which versions of StuffIt introduced backwards-incompatible changes to the file format?

Tags: apple-macintosh, software, file-format

In order to help people who want to integration-test tools which shell out to The Unarchiver's `lsar` and `unar` utilities, I'm trying to build a legally clean [repository of test archives](https://github.com/ssokolow/stuffit-test-files) in StuffIt SIT and SitX formats.

(Sort of like how Cisco pays the license fees for you if you use their prebuilt binaries of [OpenH264](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenH264).)

However, I'm having trouble finding information on which versions of StuffIt introduced backwards-incompatible changes to the format beyond Wikipedia's claim that it was common.

Can anyone provide details so I know which versions to prioritize acquiring copies of?

So far, all I know for certain is that:

1. According to [ReStuff](http://restuff.jcs.org/), StuffIt 5 introduced a format change that is incompatible with StuffIt 3.5 and earlier, StuffIt 5 cannot produce earlier version archives, and StuffIt 3.5 is the last version that runs under System 6.
2. From my own testing, StuffIt 7.0 for Windows works in Wine, apparently predates the introduction of SitX and can produce SIT archives but can only apply a Windows `.exe` self-extractor transformation to them, not SEA.
3. From my own testing, StuffIt 2009 and 2010 for Windows work in Wine, cannot make SIT archives (only SitX) and, again, can only make self-extractors for Windows.
4. From my own testing, StuffIt 2009 and 2010 for Windows *do* have a backwards-compatibility option which disables a bunch of features not supported by The Unarchiver but still produces SitX archives.